# Use the default constructor of T for the default initial value

Tags: c++, templates, default-value, default-constructor, function-declaration

> Write a function template that takes a single type parameter (T) and accepts four function arguments: an array of T, a start index, a stop index (inclusive), and an optional initial value. The function returns the sum of all the array elements in the specified range and the initial value. **Use the default constructor of T for the default initial value**. Repeat the exercise but use explicit to manually create specializations for int data type.

What is the meaning of the above line in bold?

How to have a default constructor of `T`?

Comment: `T{}` is a pretty good way to default-initialize.

Comment: Just to be 'vexing,' if the type can be inferred by the compiler, just `{}` also gets the job done. I don't recommend it for production.

Comment: Do you know what a "constructor" is?

Comment: @sweenish Try that with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`. :/

Comment: @Drew Dormann I know the meaning of a constructor with respect to a class. I am not able to understand what is the meaning of constructor with respect to T

Comment: It's just sloppy terminology. A class `C` with a default constructor support expressions creating temporaries like `C()`. But this form of initialization works for other types too. In your case, `T` is one such type that should support `T()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means something like the following

```
template <typename T>
T sum( const T a[], size_t start, size_t stop, const T &init = T() );
```

where the default value of the fourth parameter is created using the default constructor of the type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
T sum(T arr[], int start , int end,T init=T())
{
    T total=init;
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        total+=arr[i];
    }

    return total;

}

int main()
{
    

    float arr[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,55.0};
    float result=sum(arr,0,4);
    cout<<"Total : "<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```